# Command handler does not work when ran in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

The command handler for discord js does not work when ran in Heroku but works when ran locally. Most of the errors received is due to modules not being recognized by the program

Example command:

```
module.exports = {
  name: '8ball',
  description: '8ball',
  execute(receivedMessage, args) {
    if (args.length == 0) return
    receivedMessage.channel.send(response.ball())
  }
}
```

Error for command above:

```
2020-10-25T13:04:07.355215+00:00 app[web.1]: receivedMessage.channel.send(response.ball())
2020-10-25T13:04:07.355216+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2020-10-25T13:04:07.355216+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-25T13:04:07.355217+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

In the code above, 'response' is a custom module. Though the same error is raised when the discord API module is used.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. There is no `response` variable defined in your code.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `response` is declared in the main file. Which the example command is imported to. It's recognized when ran via pc but does not work when ran using Heroku.